# Textview is not showing after horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I am developing Android Application in Xamarin.Here in my code Textview is not showing.What is the problem ?

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <MvxRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mylist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listofitem"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource myitems; ItemClick ItemSelected" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="View All"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
       </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you need to change `LinearLayout` `orientation` as `vertical`!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `android:orientation="vertical"`,otherwise the layout will be set horizontally.

Comment: I want TextView beside RecyclerView that's why I have made it Horizontal.

Comment: But your TextView is set layout_gravity to center,it will not be override by Recyclerview?

Comment: No.It will set it center_vertical.if it is RelativeLayout then it can be happened.

Comment: how much is your recyclerview's width,will it fill screen width?

Comment: More than it.even if I take only one item though Textview is not showing.I don't know how it happened !

Comment: Please paste your whole xml layout,i will run it and see where is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93856/discussion-between-dhruv-gohil-and-firesun).